# is there a method to correct problem of diplaying button in highart?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, highcharts

My problem - Buttons at top aren't working
[image: Image showing problem]

I used this line chart from [here](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/stock/responsive) (so, see the code to edit in the js fiddle). I got the same code, but on my HTML page, there are problems when displaying the buttons. The code below will function normally, but if you look at the image above, the buttons are not formatted correctly in my HTML website.

Code:

```js
Highcharts.getJSON('https://demo-live-data.highcharts.com/aapl-c.json', data => {
        const chart = Highcharts.stockChart('container', {
            chart: {
                height: 400
            },
    
            title: {
                text: 'Highcharts Stock Responsive Chart'
            },
    
            subtitle: {
                text: 'Click small/large buttons or change window size to test responsiveness'
            },
    
            rangeSelector: {
                selected: 1
            },
    
            series: [{
                name: 'AAPL Stock Price',
                data: data,
                type: 'area',
                threshold: null,
                tooltip: {
                    valueDecimals: 2
                }
            }],
    
            responsive: {
                rules: [{
                    condition: {
                        maxWidth: 500
                    },
                    chartOptions: {
                        chart: {
                            height: 300
                        },
                        subtitle: {
                            text: null
                        },
                        navigator: {
                            enabled: false
                        }
                    }
                }]
            }
        });
    });
```

```css
#container {
    min-width: 310px;
    max-width: 800px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/data.js"></script>
    <div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Are you referring to the three buttons below highcharts that say "Large", "Small" and "Auto"?

Comment: I also tested your code on local configuration and everything works fine. Are you sure you are not setting additional options - width/height restrictions?